# Printing a set amount of characters

Tags: python, pyscripter

This is for a project at school, and I'm quite new to coding in python.

Basically, I am making a program that prints a set amount of 'X's and spaces, like `X X X X X...`
However, I want the user to choose how many 'X's and spaces they want to print.

This is all I've done so far:

```
xnum = input("Choose the amount of 'X's you would like to be printed")
xnum = xnum.upper()
spacenum = input("Choose the amount of spaces you would like to be printed")
linenum = input("Choose how many characters you would like to be displayed on one line")
```

I want to find out how to make the program print the number of 'X's the user asks for, and same with the spaces.

PS: I already have the code for how many characters per line, I just need some help on printing the set amount of 'X's and spaces.

Comment: Also, sorry for being short! I just didn't know how to word the paragraph. Hope it helps anyways!

Comment: do a for loop for printing. I am sure there might be better way but still for loop will work.

Comment: There's no need to uppercase the `xnum` value entered, however you will need to convert it (and the other two inputs) into integers with i.e. `xnum = int(xnum)`.

Comment: Yes I've done that, but what I'm aiming for is to get the program to print the number of X's that the user asks for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code assumes that by character you mean 'X' and not space.

```
xnum = int(input("Choose the amount of 'X's you would like to be printed\n"))
spacenum = int(input("Choose the amount of spaces you would like to be printed\n"))
linenum = int(input("Choose how many characters you would like to be displayed on one line\n"))

for i in range(xnum):
    if(i%linenum==0 and i!=0):
        print("")
    print("X", end="")
    if(spacenum!=0):
        print(" ", end="")
        spacenum -= 1
```